# ExtJS, gridfilter plugin, list type, custom filters

Tags: extjs, filtering

I have a gridpanel with the gridfilter plugin. The task is to provide filtering only in the grid's header, no other components are supposed. I load a store from the server side and some object properties in that store may consist only of several predefined strings, something like:

```
{ field: 'AAA BBB CCC' ... },{ field: 'AAA BBB' ... },
{ field: 'AAA'...}, { field: 'BBB CCC'} ..
```

Then I setup a filter for a column, I need a filter to show values which includes atleast one of those predefined strings.

```
type: 'list',
dataIndex: 'field',
options: [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
```

Is there any possibility to apply a custom function to such filter? 
Hopefully something like:

```
type: 'list',
dataIndex: 'field',
options: [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
filterFunction: function(...){
   .....
}
```

And how do I get filter values and click event, if I need to filter a store manually?

Thanks!

Comment: You want a gridcolumn with a context menu like the filter plugin provides (http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#grid-filtering) and inside that context menu predefined values?

Comment: exactly, I've got that context menu displaying those values, but I want to bind my own methods to those filters. I tried to extend the List filter class and changed it's operand from 'in' to 'like'. But looks like I need another solution